# I forgot my email address and password for my galaxy j7 how to bypass google verification

Tags: samsung-galaxy-j7

How do I get I into my account when I forgot email and password. My 4/ year old messed up my phone plz help

Comment: Has anyone ever emailed you on that address?

Answer (score 0):

Well you forgot a heck of a thing man ,  there are recovery option have u tried that ?  Might be there are chances to recover email password if you have given any alternate email or phone no.

Other thing you can do is just factory reset or hard reset your device to by pass the verification or to remove it.

This link will help you [By pass google verification](http://nepalitrend.com/how-to-remove-google-account-verification-lock-in-samsung-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a friends phone in the same state as yours. He also had a samsung device (galaxy core prime or whatever). I managed to fix it by using this tutorial. Hope it helps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhaOIrobRRk